# Sharepoint 2013 not able to open gmail link from a hyperlink column(404 error)

Tags: sharepoint-server, hyperlink, 404

I am able to open organization's internal links provided inside a hyperlink column in SharePoint 2013.
But while providing a gmail link inside the same hyperlink column throws an error in a popup:

**"404. That’s an error.  The requested URL /?IsDlg=1 was not found on this server. That’s all we know."**

Comment: Could you share a example gmail link which you want to inert to item?Link does not need to be true.

Comment: Hi Amos, <a href="https://gmail.com">gmail</a> this is complete html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact,I can not insert a gmail address to a hyperlink column.

Hyperlink description:
[image]
Test result:
[image]

As a workaround,you could add this in a multiple lines of text column.
[image]

And add this into it:

```
<a href="mailto:test@gmail.com">gmail</a>
```

Test result:

[image]